# How to keep track of object instance with Flask?

Tags: database, python-3.x, object, flask

Suppose I make a website that starts with initiating an instance of class 'Person' called 'person'.

Before saving 'person' to a database I want to manipulate some of the attributes using different html pages.

I don't understand how to keep track of the instance within Flask. How do  I instruct Flask to keep track of the instance while moving from page to page?

See this simplified example within application.py:

```
from flask import ....

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

# database stuff deleted to keep it short

class Person(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "persons"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text)
    nickname = db.Column(db.Text)

    def __init__(self, name, nickname):
        self.name = name
        self.nickname = nickname
        self.age

    def set_age(self,age):
        self.age = age

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/register", methods=["POST"])
def register():
    if request.form["name"] == "" or request.form["nickname"] == "":
        return render_template("failure.html")
    person = Person(request.form["name"], request.form["nickname"])
    db.session.add(person)
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template("add_age.html", person = person)

@app.route("/add_age")
def add_age():
    age = 23
    person.set_age = age
    return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

So I want to edit the 'age' attribute from a different page in this example.

Comment: Can you please try a little more harder to explain? It is not clear enough to help you.

Comment: for the person thing, check out flask_login using current_user. Then check out how sessions work.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't undestand your question but to do that you have to know how Flask's application context and request context work. 
Check out http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#sessions to persist data on a browser's cookie and acces from all views